# Prop minDate VueJS

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, vue.js

Estou tendo uma dificuldade com uma propriedade Vue que eu não acho solução em lugar nenhum.
Estou utilizando um v-flatpickr para seleção de data, e usei um minDate como data mínima de seleção de data, passando um new Date() como dia mínimo.

`v-flatpickr="{ allowInput: true, 'altFormat': 'd/m/Y', dateFormat: 'd/m/Y', minDate: new Date() }"`

Quando seleciono datas superiores a data de hoje funciona certinho, porém quando seleciono exatamente o dia de hoje, some a data que eu selecionei e passa para o backend um valor null.
Alguém saberia como resolver isso para que passe certinho o dia de hoje?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que pode ser o formato que você definiu, já q o *new Date()* retorna uma string completa da data:

```
console.log(new Date())
// imprime algo como "Sat Oct 02 2021 19:32:21 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)"
```

como você já colocou o padrão brasileiro de data nos outros campos, acredito que a solução poderia ser algo como:

```
v-flatpickr="{ allowInput: true, 'altFormat': 'd/m/Y', dateFormat: 'd/m/Y', minDate: (new Date()).toLocaleDateString("pt-BR") }"
```